# PostgreSQL trigger for statement explanation

Tags: postgresql, trigger, materialized-view

**PostgreSQL 14**

I try to understand the behaviour of trigger for `each statement`.

Here is an example :

```
    AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE 
    ON mytbl
    FOR EACH STATEMENT
    EXECUTE FUNCTION myfunc();
```

- No matter how many `insert` or `update` or `delete` in `mytbl`, `myfunc()` will be executed just one time, only at the end of DML?
- myfunc() does 8 `REFRESH materialized views` commands through a `FOR...LOOP`. But in the log I can only read one `CONTEXT : SQL statement "refresh materialized view amatview"`. But later I see `automatic vacuum` and `analyze` for all the materialized views. Are all the 8 views refreshed anyway?

Comment: The trigger will run for each insert statement.